# Should new users be allowed to upvote questions and/or answers?

Tags: discussion, new-users, upvotes

Especially on Stack Overflow, I see more and more upvotes appearing on questions that clearly don't deserve an upvote. These questions hardly follow any of the Guidelines and usually lack any code or even a relevant question.

I assume these upvotes come from different new user accounts trying to make it appear as if the question is actually very good and get more attention towards them that way. Lately I even noticed someone upvoting any question and all answers to it, whether they were good or not.

Personally I think the reputation is a good system. But it loses it's value if everyone starts receiving reputation for no reason at all. It even happened to me yesterday. I don't know your vision on this, but I like the idea that I've actually earned the reputation I got. Not because some new users start spamming upvotes everywhere.

**Edit:**

After reading some of the comments here, I think I should clerify some things. I'm *not* complaining about upvotes on questions or answers that I personally disagree with. I'm talking about upvotes on questions and anwers that clearly don't fit in the Guidelines. Questions and/or answers that are technically completely wrong and should've been a comment instead.

One could argue that you can give a better answer to help out. I agree. But that's a workaround. It doesn't solve the issue at hand. Users still get reputation they didn't deserve. For now this is still just a minor problem. But if it isn't stopped, I garantuee we're going to see a lot more strange upvotes in the near future.

Also, some here thought I was talking about removing the ability to upvote for low rep users completely. This is not the case at all. I was more thinking to slightly alter it:

- Upvoting questions: Require 15 Rep (as it currently is).
- Upvoting answers: Require 50 Rep (or whatever seems appropriate).

This way you still allow low rep users to cast upvotes. Yet they can't cause problems to the reputation system in general. Very bad questions that gain upvotes, are neutralised once they get deleted.

*So why do I want to limit upvotes on answers?*
Well there are several reasons. But the most important one is this: Lets say a very bad answer gets a couple of upvotes. The question is already a bit old and doesn't get much attention from the high rep users anymore. Somewhere in the future, a user has the same question. He finds the question and sees the upvoted answer. Can you imagine their confusion that the answer doesn't help them at all but is still upvoted? This will no longer just be a problem about unfair reputation, but the reputation of Stack Overflow in general as being a trustworthy resource!

Comment: I think many of those votes come from low rep users simply voting based on the other user being low rep.  Some sort of renegade, *Fight the Injustice* against low-rep users type thing.

Comment: There are just toooo many low rep users which upV's incorrect content and also don't even know how SO works and just not enough high rep users which are fighting against it! Because the relation between low/high rep is like: 5:1 when not even higher! `So either high rep users needs more privileges so that they can deal with incorrect information or and low rep users less`

Comment: I agree with you. On these bad questions, this is not really an issue. The questions usually get closed and any reputation is removed. But now it's happening on all questions and all answers. Regardless of who posted them. And that's where it does become an issue.

Comment: A "new user account" cannot upvote posts, it requires 15 rep.  Somebody that brainlessly votes usually has a very hard time getting there.  You'll need to ignore what's been going on these past few weeks, the students will disappear again in June when they go on vacation or start their summer jobs.

Comment: @HansPassant But I think a *real* problem is still, that there are either just not enough high right users which do something about incorrect content or they just have not enough power. Stack Overflow has at some point to decide between "A hill of programming beginners" or the *real* coders.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's really a perfect example of what's going on lately. That's exactly why I thought it nessesary to get some attention to this issue.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well, there is the small problem that you *shouldn't* be flagging as Not An Answer in that instance. There are *tons* of threads around meta explaining that. Your hostility is completely unwarranted.

Comment: a somewhat similar idea is to [get rid of _first day voting_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183109/the-association-bonus-should-not-enable-users-to-vote-on-every-site/183568#comment781260_237661), "...wanna vote? stick with us! (for at least a day or two)"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with this proposal that I see:

- Voting is **anonymous**.  We can't say for certain that it's *just* low-rep users upvoting questions or content that others may not feel the same way about.
- Voting is **subjective.** Did you hear about the time that [Tim lost his keys?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/175248)  Not just that, but there's no controlling a user from upvoting or downvoting a question; they can do that on a whim or because they felt like it.  The only time that this is actively restricted is in the case of voting fraud; a few examples would be sock puppet accounts upvoting each other's content, and serial upvoting/downvoting.

I don't have any qualms with users upvoting content that I personally disagree with; at the same time, I don't have any qualms downvoting content that I feel should be downvoted.  But saying that new users can't vote?  You're painting a very large group of people with a very broad brush here.

Comment: It isn't about content which you disagree with, `it's about technical` **incorrect** `information!` And there is no choice if you dis/agree with, it's just wrong and you can't do anything against this stuff. *And that's a real problem!*

Comment: Remember when I said that voting was subjective?  Although technically I do agree with you in spirit, I don't just downvote answers that are technically incorrect - I downvote answers that are inefficient, incomplete, unclear, or don't accomplish the task at hand.  Consequently, questions are downvoted if they're not clear or not useful, although the latter is much harder to pinpoint.

Comment: Wait - are you just not willing to downvote content?

Comment: Nah I just want to say if 2 users come by an answer and they upV it even if it is technical incorrect, as a single person you can't do much and even if you are like 3 guys which downV. The guy with the answer still gains positive reputation from it and you can show him with X comments that his answer is just incorrect, he won't delete it until he gets into the negative. And I saw this a lot in the last 2-3 weeks.

Comment: You've outlined a few of the most common tactics that I personally use when faced with this situation.  The next logical step is to provide a **correct** answer, explaining *why* it's correct, and building from there.  You have more power than you give yourself credit for here.

Comment: ^ Now you're on a fence: a) Post your own answer and show the facts and whats correct OR b) Correct the other answer. Either way the guy who asked the question will still be confused and you have to explain him all why the other answer was incorrect and compared to how many incorrect answers there are this is a *real* pain! (In my case most times PHP related) And just the relation between people who know stuff and technical incorrect answers is like: 1:5! In other words: *You're just flooded* <- And against this I sadly can't do anything..

Comment: *What* fence?  All you can do is admonish the other user, downvote them, *or* post your own answer.  There *is* no correcting their answer.  The main thing here that I think you're encountering is askers that are more interested in a quick fix than the actual solution, and you shouldn't get discouraged from that.  I strongly encourage you to post answers that are correct and continue explaining why this is correct *without* overstepping your bounds (e.g. yelling at the other person in their comments box).  Otherwise, take a bit of a break and try again at a future time.  Don't lose hope.

Comment: Anyway, I'm already ^ doing that, but a fact is just that it takes you longer to clean the entire mess up than they need time to post something incorrect. So it's a fight which you can't win.

Comment: Also just to add a little harmless example for the end here what I mean: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29290455 <- 1. line of the manual just completely says that the answer is not correct. (And that example is pretty harmless compared to others)

Comment: You are right. I've futher clerified my question to what exactly I ment. As I didn't mean to completely cut of low rep users from voting. Hope you better understand my point of view on this now.

Comment: Your answer doesn't have to explain why all the others or wrong, it just has to be right and explain some common misconceptions or roughly glaze over some problems of other answers. Who cares if others get upvotes if yours gets more?

Comment: @nhgrif It's not that I care about others getting upvotes. Even if they didn't deserve them. I care about the consequenses of these upvotes to SO in general. Upvoted answers tend to be reliable and high rep users are usually considdered trustworthy. If this strange upvoting trent gets out of hand, both those answers and high rep users will face the consequences like losing credability in general.

Comment: Do you have evidence it is **getting out of hand**?

Comment: Personally? No. But all you have to do is take a look at newly formed questions, especially during night-time. Then again, I said **IF** it gets out of hand. I did mention before that it's still a minor problem. But it's happening more and more frequently as of late. Read others comments here about that. I'm not the only one noticing it.

Comment: After reading your link to "Tim lost his keys", I understand what you're saying. It doesn't mean I like it or still hope there's a solution for this, but I do understand that it's something that can't be controlled unless half the system is reworked and moderators actively start monitoring every vote. Which simply is a task that just can't be done on this scale. Thanks for explaning and sorry for the long wait on accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a **reputation deflation** in Stack Exchange communities, i.e. it gets harder and harder to get reputation, so reputation is *worth* more.

This is made obvious by the guidelines to upvote a lot in beta, and by the fact that every question that is answered is a question that new users won't be able to answer. **This is not fundamentaly a bad thing.**

However, it causes bad things. Low quality answers and reputation vampires exist more because of the deflation. The easier it is to ask a good question that wasn't asked before, the less incentive you have to answer poorly for the quick 15 rep.

Of course, it is good to know that the website is getting more and more complete, and the deflation is not important as long as the website serves its goal.

Thus I don't think that we should actively fight the deflation - but we shouldn't help it either. Demoting upvotes from new users will probably cut short some reputation vampires - but low quality questions are asked everyday, and 100 to 200 rep users can be part of it.

Demoting upvotes will make new users feel more austracized, less part of the community. This is something SO has been struggling with in the past. It will also strongly reinforce the deflation, stopping new users to be an active part of the community by stopping them from having access to more tools.

**In short**, I think banning new users from voting would be a short-timed solution to a problem that grows everyday, and that it would stop newcomers from integrating into the community.

Answer (score 2):

As a new user and tyro at programming, I like the ability to upvote, it makes me feel part of something. Because of that feeling I'm more conscientious about trying to word my questions properly and research the site a bit before asking what probably seem like simple questions to others. If that ability wasn't there, this place would lose it's 'community' spirit.... my rep gains mean little to me, but obviously others like it, so happy to upvote them and help them out if their Question/anser helped me solve a problem and/or gave me a good idea.... so I reckon it should be left as is until it breaks something.... just my two cents

Comment: What about not being able to downvote?

Comment: I don't think I'd be comfortable downvoting anything, but hey, I just got here, give me another month ;)