# Vote up privilege for new users on their own questions

Tags: discussion, reputation, upvotes, privileges

A minimum of 15 reputation is [required](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) to upvote. Shouldn't users with less rep be allowed to upvote answers on their own questions?

Comment: Great for sockpuppets

Comment: They can accept an answer. That is enough for starters. They know what worked for them, give them a bit of time to learn what a valuable post looks like.

Comment: Since you likely already researched why that restriction is put in place please [edit] post to explain that so other don't have to...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293915/should-new-users-be-allowed-to-upvote-questions-and-or-answers

Comment: A single upvote on the question, and accepting the answer gets the OP to 13 reputation; I'm sure the OP can find another way to get that crucial 2 reputation if they really need it to upvote the answer as well.

Answer (score 15):

The vote-up privilege already is already very easy to obtain (and even easier since the question up-vote reward has been adjusted).

What's the argument for users being allowed to vote before they get to 15 points? Are they more knowledgeable of the site's rules and culture because it's them asking the question?

More likely, they are not (some even have trouble with the "acceptance" feature), so it's better they spend a bit longer before they can start upvoting.